# Devise - don't want to open reset password page in case of token is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using `devise gem`.

I don't want to open the Reset password page (received at my email) if the **Devise** `forget_password_token` is not valid or already used.

Right now by default, it asks me to add a new password and password confirmation then when I submit, it say's **"token has been expired"**

I just want to add a concept of expire device reset password link sent at the email.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: So you want to validate the token when the link is loaded initially?

Comment: Absolutely right @Ricks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of devise you're using. So I will explain my idea by referring to `devise 3.2.4`.

In `devise` there is a module that is called `Recoverable`. You can look at it [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2.4/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb). In this module, you can find a method `reset_password_period_valid?`

It looks like that:

```
def reset_password_period_valid?
  reset_password_sent_at && reset_password_sent_at.utc >= self.class.reset_password_within.ago.utc
end
```

You can start with this method. 
The second thing is to work with methods in a special controller, look at `PasswordsController` in `devise`. You can look at it [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.2.4/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb).

Methods that you can overwrite or modify:

```
# GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef
def edit
  self.resource = resource_class.new
  resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
end

# PUT /resource/password
def update
  self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)
  yield resource if block_given?

  if resource.errors.empty?
    resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
    flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
    set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
  else
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bro, I'm using devise 4.5.0.
But I do not want to open password reset page again if the token is used once.
In your solution, there is nothing in Edit action, right?
Actually, I wanna show page expire message here 

# GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef

Comment: @JaiKumarRajput Do you use the default Devise controller or you have overwritten it? Do you want to store somewhere information that some tokens have been used?